# Understanding short hand for loops in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, shorthand

I am very new to C++. I am trying to figure out this sample short hand for loop from my book, it is very long and ugly and was wondering if this can be re written in a cleaner way. Ignore the functions in there like before() and others, they are part of a linked list program I am working on. I just do not understand from my book how to re write the loop in a more "traditional" way. Thanks in advance!

```
fooExample(string str){

    string s = toLower(str);

    for(books->setEnd();!books->atStart() && (toLower(books->getInfo().getAuthor()).search(s)==string::npos);books->before());

}
```

Comment: This is exceptionally awful code; if your book recommends this code then you should get a different book.

Comment: Like one of these [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @user2438839, Out of curiosity, which one?

Comment: `books->setEnd()` initializes the loop, so it is called before the loop. Everything before the next ';' is called before every step into the loop, and only if the whole thing returns `true` the loop is entered. `&&` returns true if both parts return true. `books->before()` is then executed to 'step forward' on every 'enter the loop'

Comment: Exposing a reverse iterator through `rbegin()` and `rend()` and then using `std::find_if` strikes me as the traditional way here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form for for-loops in C++ looks like this:

```
for(initialisation; condition; incrementation)
{
    //code
}
```

So you could do something like

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

The principle in your code is the same; there is an initialisation, a condition, and not really an "incrementation", but something that happens every iteration of the loop(I guess it goes to the previous book).

Comment: what would I do with the "&&"? I just cannot figure out how to re write this in the normal for loop style.

Comment: `condition1 && condition2` means that `condition1` **and** `condition2` have to evaluate to true in order for the result to be true. So it is completely valid, and there is nothing wrong with using && in a for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

say we have a vector of int

```
vector<int> myvector;
```

we can use

```
for(auto iter : myvector){
    dosomething...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling the loop into a more typical state yields:

```
for(books->setEnd(); !books->atStart(); books->before())
{
     if (toLower(books->getInfo().getAuthor()).search(s) == string::npos)
         break;
}
```

The author took the body of the loop, which is just a conditional break, and added it to the loop condition.